# Could my MBP be breaking power bricks?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, charging, power

I have a 2019 MBP Touch Bar. A month ago, my stock 87W brick stopped working. (Not a cable issue, etc., definitely the brick.) Bought a replacement 96W brick off Amazon — not Apple, but with good reviews. Today, that failed too. (Again, it’s the brick.)

That seems a little suspect. Could my MBP be drawing too much power, breaking the bricks? Could something else be causing this? It could be coincidence, of course, but that seems unlikely.

Anyone hear of anything similar?

Comment: Coincidence is likely when buying cheap stuff. I bought anApple power brick last year and it is fine.

Comment: For Amazon etc look at the bad reviews - if there are several all saying similar things then they are more likely to be correct than the 5 star ones.